# Find the amplitude of the complex number $(\frac{1}{1-2i}+\frac{3}{1+i})(\frac{3+4i}{2-4i}).$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Find the amplitude of the complex number $(\frac{1}{1-2i}+\frac{3}{1+i})(\frac{3+4i}{2-4i}).$

My solution goes like this:

> We consider $z=(\frac{1}{1-2i}+\frac{3}{1+i})(\frac{3+4i}{2-4i})=(\frac{1+2i}{5}+3\frac{1-i}{2})(\frac{(3+4i)(2+4i)}{20})=(\frac{17}{10}-\frac{11i}{10})(i-\frac12)=\frac14+\frac94i.$ Thus $|z|=\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}.$ Hence, $z=\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}(\frac{\frac14}{\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}}+\frac{\frac94i}{\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}}).$ Thus, $\cos\theta=\frac{\frac14}{\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}}$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{\frac94}{\sqrt{\frac{41}{8}}}.$ And $\theta$ is the amplitude of $z$.

Is the above solution correct?

I found this problem on a handout of problems and the source of this problem is unknown (to me). But I think, it's a standard problem.

Comment: 1) get red of $i$ in your final expression of $\sin \theta$. 2) Divide $\sin \theta$ by   $\cos\theta$ to get $\tan \theta$, giving the final answer  $\theta=\tan^{-1}9$ 3) Use a computer to check your values.

Comment: @JeanMarie +1. To OP: `python` does complex calculations for free.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for pointing out the typo ...But as far as I know, it's not advisable to check for argument or amplitude using $\tan^{-1}$ as often, it doesn't provide a $\theta$ satisfying both the values of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. Also, computers are not allowed in exam. So, will my solution hold valid? (Provided if I present in this way  as done in my post)

Comment: "It doesn't provide a $\theta$..." ??? As your sine and cosine are positive, your complex number is situated in the first quadrant : so, no risk using $\tan^{-1}$.$\tan^{-1}(9)$ is the final answer that is asked from you. The fact that it cannot be expressed in another way isn't your fault ! You don't need a computer ; you leave the answer like this.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot for your clarifications! Understood.

Comment: Are you sure _amplitude_ is meant to be $\theta$ (usually called the _argument_ or _phase_) instead of $r$ (usually called the _modulus_, _magnitude_ or _amplitude_)? (In case anyone thinks some of my names sound made up, talk to physicists.)

Comment: @J.G.  Yeah , in this case argument holds the same meaning as amplitude and in many texts of complex numbers I have seen they being used synonymously...

Answer (score 1):

Write your first parenthesis as $$\frac{1+2i}{5}+\frac{3-3i}{2}=\frac{17-11i}{10}$$Write the second parenthesis as $$\frac{-5+10i}{10}=\frac{-1+2i}{2}$$ Your whole expression is $$\frac{5+45i}{20}=\frac{1+9i}{4}$$ The magnitude is $$\frac{\sqrt 82}{4}$$